# Running Functions with Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to call functions within other functions

So if I do this it will work: all I am doing here is from my `SearchUpdater(text)` function calling the `Updater` function, and it works.

```
class Search2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
    };
  }

Updater(text){
       var newArray = []
        newArray.push(text)
          this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray),
          });

}


  SearchUpdater(text){


  this.Updater(text)




  }
```

However, if I want to run some functions within `SearchUpdater` (I have some complicated logic I want to put in.. makes it easier) it will say `this.updater` is undefined...

```
class Search2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
    };
  }

Updater(text){
       var newArray = []
        newArray.push(text)
          this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray),
          });

}


  SearchUpdater(text){

  var ComplicatedLogicFunc = function(){
      this.Updater("HEYO")

  }
  ComplicatedLogicFunc();



  }
```

Any help would be great..
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `this` keyword in your inner function (`var ComplicatedLogicFunc`) is not referencing `Search2` instance.

For this example, you could either use [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (which preserve the value of `this`):

```
var ComplicatedLogicFunc = () => {
    this.Updater("HEYO");
};
```

explicitly bind `this` keyword to the function call context:

```
ComplicatedLogicFunc.call(this);
```

or you could simply store your local context in another variable like this:

```
SearchUpdater(text) {
    var self = this;

    var ComplicatedLogicFunc = function(){
        self.Updater("HEYO")
    }

    ComplicatedLogicFunc();
}
```

You can read more about how `this` keyword works in JavaScript here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this